# Is it possible to run different iOS projects with button click?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I have four apps and want to combine them into one app.

If I added those projects into a project workspace -- for example there's project A and project B --
is it possible to click a button and go to project A's root controller, 
then click another button go to project B's root controller ?

If it's possible, how can I do that?

Comment: What is the meaning "go to project A root controller"?

Comment: after button click go to project A's storyboard and run it's root view controller

Comment: Make a container view controller and add the entry points of your two apps to that container. Add a button to the container view controllers view. Add an action which loads the entry points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is it possible to click a button and go to project A's root
>   controller, then click another button go to project B's root
>   controller?

A natural way to do that would be to manage the various "root" view controllers with a tab bar controller. For example, your app delegate could create a `UITabBarController` programmatically, and then load it with the root view controllers from each of your storyboards. It'd go something like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

    // Project 1
    UIStoryboard *storyboard1 = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Project1" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *controller1 = [storyboard1 instantiateInitialViewController];

    // Project 2
    UIStoryboard *storyboard2 = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Project2" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *controller2 = [storyboard1 instantiateInitialViewController];

    // Project 3
    UIStoryboard *storyboard3 = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Project3" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *controller3 = [storyboard1 instantiateInitialViewController];

    // Project 4
    UIStoryboard *storyboard4 = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Project4" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *controller4 = [storyboard1 instantiateInitialViewController];

    // Add the controllers to the tab controller
    [self.tabBarController setViewControllers:@[controller1, controller2, controller3, controller4]
                                     animated:NO];

    //...put any other app initialization stuff here...

    return YES;
}
```

At this point the tab bar will have four buttons, one for each "root" view controller, and you'll be able to switch between them at will.

I haven't compiled the above, but it should be enough to get you started. You will of course have to sort out any dependancies that the various view controllers might have on the app delegate, etc. But that shouldn't be too difficult. You should also make sure that each view controller is configured with a tab bar item, so that the tab bar controller will know what icon and name to use on the corresponding button.